# Passing two parameters at once in Rails Ransack

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried with one parameter and now i want search form to work for both title and body with once search button via UI. 
http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&ved=0CEIQtwIwAw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DAB_D-G7wAsc&ei=2Fk5UoXhH8forQeDkYGAAw&usg=AFQjCNGog91uLZoTOCPLsVsxp9pZk7CpPA&bvm=bv.52288139,d.bmk

Answer (score 0):

You can use fields with names like

```
User.search(:title_or_body_cont => "Rya").result
```

see [Ransack dokumentation](https://github.com/ernie/ransack/wiki/Basic-Searching)

`Ransack`'s `search` method takes a hash of predicates and values, in the above example

{ :title_or_body => "Ray" }

the form helper `search_form_for` wraps the input fields so that all predicates are sent as a hash with the name `q` (of cause, you can change this in the configuration, but it`s better to stay with the convention).
So a form like

```
<% search_form_for @search do |f| %>
  <%= f.content_cont %>
  <%= f.title_or_body_cont %>
<% end %>
```

will return a parameter `:q` containing the hash

```
params[:q] ==> { :content_cont => "foo", :title_or_body_cont => "bar" }
```

and your controller can create a new search like

```
@search = Post.search(params[:q])
@posts = @search.result
```

where "bar" is searched alternatively in `title` or `body` and "foo" is searched in `content`.

Comment: could you please add your code to the question and format it (indent by 4 spaces)